# How can I pass a parameter pack to a void pointer in C++?

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, std-function

Please consider the following code example:

```cpp
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

template <typename... Ts>
class SomeClass
{
public:
    std::function<bool(Ts...)> some_func;

    void run(Ts... args)
    {
        this->some_func(args...); // this works

        this->thread_run((void *)&this->some_func, args); // this won't work, can't pass the parameter pack
    }

    static void thread_run(void *func_ptr, void *args_ptr)
    {
        auto thread_func = *(std::function<bool(Ts...)> *)(func_ptr);
        thread_func(2, 3);
    }
};

int main()
{
    SomeClass<int, int> a;

    a.some_func = [](int x, int y)
    { std::cout << "Arguments: " << x << " " << y << std::endl; return x > y; };

    a.run(2, 3);

    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, there is a class that has a template `std::function` member variable. I can set it by giving it a lambda expression that must return `bool` but can have any number of arguments, which is nice!

Sadly, I am now given the task to run this function as a thread with a given threading library (which is non-negotiable). The entry function for the threading library has to be a `static` function with the following signature:

`void (*thread_entry_t)(void *p1, void *p2)`

I've managed to pass the `std::function` variable to the `static` function in the example, see the `thread_run()` function, but I can't find a way to pass the parameter pack `args` to the `static` function through the `void*` pointers.

How could I do it?

Comment: Pass a `std::tuple`?

Comment: I've never used parameter packs, but after some quick reading I think these packs are actually implemented as multiple arguments and there is no trivial way to convert multiple arguments into a single void pointer without knowing the actual number of arguments and their types. Indeed you need something more specific such as a tuple.

Comment: `auto args_tuple = std::make_tuple(args...); thread_run(&some_func, &args_tuple);` And inside `thread_run` use [`std::apply`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/apply)

Comment: BTW, unclear how is the library function? what is `p1`, `p2`, who provide them?

Comment: Why would you need to do that? Can't you just use `std::jthread` for multi-threading? I guess you're trying to use some platform specific threading library. Why not try the `std` version?!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can wrap `args...` in a tuple, and pass a pointer to that. I've made it a member of your class so that it has the same lifetime as the `std::function` object.

```
template <typename... Ts>
class SomeClass
{
public:
    std::function<bool(Ts...)> some_func;
    std::tuple<Ts...> args;

    void run(Ts... args)
    {
        this->args = { args... };    
        thread_run((void *)&this->some_func, (void *)&this->args);
    }

    static void thread_run(void *func_ptr, void *args_ptr)
    {
        auto & thread_func = *(std::function<bool(Ts...)> *)(func_ptr);
        auto & args = *(std::tuple<Ts...> *)(args_ptr);
        std::apply(thread_func, args);
    }
};
```

Comment: You don't need `this->`, just rename one of the `args`. And you don't need the `void*` typecasts. And you should use `static_cast` instead  of C-style casts.